# newton json default string value not working?

Tags: c#, json.net

When I seralise an object, for some string properties, I would like to output empty string other than ignore or output null.

According to newton's doc, I could do this:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [DefaultValue("")]
    [JsonProperty(DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include)]

    public string LargeData { get; set; }
}
```

However, in my test case, it still output null

```
Data D1 = new Data()
{
     ProductId = 1
};

var b = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(D1);
```

The output is `{"ProductId":1,"LargeData":null}`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at [`DefaultValueHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_DefaultValueHandling.htm) it doesn't look like there's any way of doing what you want.

The default value attribute is only used when *deserializing*, if the property isn't specified in the JSON. The ignore / include choices are the ones which are relevant when *serializing*, and those don't affect the value that's serialized - just whether or not it *should* be serialized.

Unless you've got code which actually sets the value to null, the simplest option would be to make the property default to "" from a .NET perspective:

```cs
public class Data
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string LargeData { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Comment: indeed, you are right, it can't be done easily. Unless I do some custom Resolver